# Create a Kotlin library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am very new to both the Android and JVM platforms.  Using Android Studio, I would like to create an Android app and put most of my business logic in a library. I would also like to just use Kotlin, no Java.

When I go to `File` > `New Module`, the options listed are

- Phone & Tablet module
- Android Library
- Instant App
- Feature Module
- Android Wear Module
- Android TV Module
- Android Things Module
- Import Gradle Project
- Import Eclipse ADT Project
- Import .JAR/.AAR Package
- Java Library

I can create a Kotlin-based library with the `Android Library` option, but this also includes a lot of files for dealing with resources and controls.

I just want a pure Kotlin library.  What is the easiest way to create one?

- Can I delete a portion of an Android Library?
- Can I change some settings in a Java Library?
- Can I download a plugin that will just give me the option to create a Kotlin library?

I am still a bit confused the file organization in Java/Kotlin/Android projects.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need a module with no Android dependencies and resources - this is what a *Java library* module does, so you start by creating one of those. From there, you just need to enable Kotlin inside this module.

The `build.gradle` file you get when you create your module is something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

You need to add the Kotlin plugin and standard library. If you don't have the `mavenCentral` repository added for all modules in your project yet, you need to add that as well:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

This is assuming that you have a `kotlin_version` declared in your project level `build.gradle` file, which is the usual way for Android projects, and I believe that's how Android Studio configures a project if you tick the checkbox to use Kotlin.

---

With those changes to your library's `build.gradle`, you can remove the automatically generated `MyClass.java` file from your library's source folder (`/src/main/java/your/package/name`), and start adding Kotlin files instead. If you'd like, you can also rename the `/src/main/java` folder to `/src/main/kotlin`. Or you can use both folders, this is entirely up to you.

Comment: "Plugin version is not the same as library version" warning: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956051/warning-kotlin-plugin-version-is-not-the-same-as-library-version-but-it-is

Comment: How would I make kotlin classes package private so that apps that use my library cannot import those files?

Comment: @viper look into the `internal` visibiity, that's what you want in libraries a lot of the time.

Comment: Unable to find a matching configuration of project :DD_kotlin_lib: None of the consumable configurations have attributes - though the library builds successfully

Comment: @zsmb13 Is there a comprehensive explanation why "Java or Kotlin Library" module can't use Android dependencies? In terms of resources and similar stuff it is clear - we have no access to android.jar, right? But what if I want to reference livedata dependencies, why that's not allowed, also because of transient dependencies on android.jar? "Java or Kotlin Library" should be separated from any OS runtime?

Comment: LiveData's internals will depend on things that only exist on the Android platform, such as the Android main thread's Looper. Therefore, it's not possible to use that class on the JVM outside of Android, because the Android framework's components are not available (basically, the android.jar, as you said).

Answer (score -3):

Create Android studio project 
After that create as many as module which are basically Android library 
You can select the language of module (java/kotlin)

Extra 
Upload your module to github and use jitpcak tool to make your module a library like this 
Implementation 'com. My. Module:1.0'

And use your module any future project

Comment: Old post but I would like to correct this. OP wants to add a new module to act as the business layer. An Android Module is not the way to do this, OP needs a "Java Library". According to clean architecture, inner modules must not contain anything related to Android APIs. The Android Module adds a lot of Android specific folders and components and they must be removed to adhere to the clean arcihtecture, which is a lot of work. The accepted answer is the easiest way to do this.