# Warning "Kotlin plugin version is not the same as library version" (but it is!)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I have an Android studio project in which I have added a Java library module, which I call `core`. My three Gradle build files look like this.

project/build.gradle

```gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.40'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

core/build.gradle

```gradle
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies { 
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
    ...
}
```

app/build.gradle

```gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android { ... }

dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The problem I have is that, in `core/build.gradle`, the `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` line is giving me the warning `Plugin version (1.2.40) is not the same as library version (jdk7-1.2.40)`. I have tried changing it to:

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"`

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.40"`

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.40"`

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"`

`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"`

But the warning is still there. The build still runs successfully, and I know I can surpress the warning without any problems and ignore it, but I really want to know why this is happening and how I can get rid of it. I am using Android Studio 3.0.1. Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Starting from [Kotlin 1.4](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library-added-by-default) dependency on the standard library added by default:

> You no longer need to declare a dependency on the stdlib library in any Kotlin Gradle project, including a multiplatform one. The dependency is added by default.
>
> The automatically added standard library will be the same version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, since they have the same versioning.
>
> For platform-specific source sets, the corresponding platform-specific variant of the library is used, while a common standard library is added to the rest. The Kotlin Gradle plugin will select the appropriate JVM standard library depending on the kotlinOptions.jvmTarget compiler option of your Gradle build script.

[Link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#dependency-on-the-standard-library) to Kotlin Gradle plugin documentation.

Comment: this is the correct answer, e.g. you don't need `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"` any longer

Comment: So the bug is on the android studio template for a new lib or project, it brings this dependency as default.

Comment: @Spatz: Could you please provide any official statements / links from Jetbrains for above change.

Comment: @SVK [Kotlin 1.4.0-RC Released](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/07/kotlin-1-4-rc-released/)

Comment: @HeltonIsac it even says to do that in official Android Studio docs: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/add-kotlin

Answer (score 143):

This is a bug in the Kotlin plugin. I've filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23933) in the Kotlin issue tracker. You can simply ignore the message.

EDIT: JetBrains marked the issue as a duplicate of [KT-23744](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23744) "Kotlin library and Gradle plugin versions are different" inspection false positive for non-JVM dependencies".

Comment: KT-23744  has been marked as fixed and should be fixed in `1.3.20`. However i am still facing this issue on android studio for kotlin plugin version `1.3.20-release-Studio3.3-1`. On IntelliJ for kotlin plugin version `1.3.20-release-IJ2018.3-1`, i am not having this issue.

Comment: Just remove this line from your build.gradle and the warning will be gone:
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Seems like we could just remove the stdlib line starting from kotlin 1.4 according to answer below.

Comment: y'all need to see the below answer by @Spatz https://stackoverflow.com/a/64988522/9316730

    `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"`

is no longer required

Answer (score 14):

Solution, in my case, I got rid of the line
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
in the app level Gradle and the warning disappear
As the Kotlin page says :
" You no longer need to declare a dependency on the stdlib library in any Kotlin Gradle project, including a multiplatform one. The dependency is added by default.

```
The automatically added standard library will be the same version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, since they have the same versioning.

For platform-specific source sets, the corresponding platform-specific variant of the library is used, while a common standard library is added to the rest. The Kotlin Gradle plugin will select the appropriate JVM standard library depending on the kotlinOptions.jvmTarget compiler option of your Gradle build script."
```

Answer (score 5):

You might be facing this after upgrading kotlin version, Actually, older versions are still in your caches, In this case, you need to do the following steps

1. Invalidate cache
2. Clean project
3. Sync project with gradle files

Now your warning will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

[build.gradle(Module)]

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10'
    ...
}
```

My project automatically added

```
(implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.10')
```

to the project build file. After moving the implementation to the module file, and removing

```
(implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10')
```

the warning went away.
The 'stdlib' needs to match the 'stdlib-jdk' in the module file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while using Firebase with Kotlin.
I had to upgrade all the dependencies with their latest version available.

**Note: have your kotlin-reflect and kotlin-stdlib versions same.**

Answer (score 0):

after many days i  have solve the  issue
Update  the kotlin_version to '1.4.32'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set the version number for all modules the same as gradle of `app` as latest version, and problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `kotlin-stdlib`, you can override how the jdk versions are resolved in your app/build.gradle

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75298544/7360275) for more details.