# Create Kotlin Library

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependencies

I am trying to achieve what is extremely simply in other languages, however I am new to Kotlin and Android Studio.
I wish, when creating a project, to reuse code by having it in a seperate directory to the project, but to be able to create instances of a Kotlin class in a given project, and also to be able to edit the class definitions and rebuild the 'library' in that open project

Before anyone shoots me I have read

[Create a Kotlin library in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583488/create-a-kotlin-library-in-android-studio)

this however does not work and simply results in [image]

Comment: Did you add kotlin dependency to both app and library build.gradle? Can you add your build.gradle files to understand the problem?

Comment: which files are these please

Comment: build.gradle file in your project and in your library

Comment: Unable to find a matching configuration of project :My_kotlin_lib: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.